# Active workers vs Active users

Tags: mining-pools

In a mining pool, it says that there are active workers and active users. What is the difference between them? And does the block get divided per worker or per user?

Answer (score 3):

- `worker` is analogous to the number of connections.
- `username` is just a way of identifying specific miners in the list of connections and
  to which account on the pool they belong to. They don't have any
  impact on the work given.

Answer (score 0):

For exemple you have an account in a mining pool ( You are ONE user), you have 5 ASIC in your farm, for every asic you give a worker name (You have FIVE workers)

All the work of your 5 ASIC will work for your username

PS: Generally miners give for every asic a worker name to identify a particular ASIC in case of a problem